# How to migrate WAS 7.5 to Liberty Profile 8.5?

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-was

I am looking to migrate my application to run on Liberty profile 8.5 instead of Websphere Application server 7.5. In this process, I need to do server configuration by setting up LDAP, Database source and JMS. As I am new to Liberty profile, I am looking for help in setting up these. May I get some suggestions from you to complete these settings?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit broad question, so I'll give you some pointers to documentation to get you started (There is no WAS 7.5, so you probably mean 7.0).

- [WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile Guide for Developers](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248076.html?Open) - this will give you some basic general information to get you started with Liberty
- Data source configuration - basic configuration is quite simple, you define it in `server.xml` file (you didn't mention which DB you are using, so here is sample with Derby)

> ```
> <library id="derby">
>   <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/derby"/>
> </library>
> <jdbcDriver id="derbyDriver" libraryRef="derby"/>
> <dataSource jdbcDriverRef="derbyDriver" jndiName="jdbc/DataSourceJNDI" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
>   <properties.derby.embedded createDatabase="false" databaseName="D:\path\DB"/>
> </dataSource>
> ```

For more specific information regarding migrating DB2 data sources see 
[Migrating a DB2 data source to the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_migrate_ds_db2.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-0-0-2&lang=en)

- LDAP configuration - basic configuration for MS Active Directory

> ```
> <ldapRegistry id="ldap" realm="SampleLdapADRealm"
>     host="ldapserver.mycity.mycompany.com" port="389" ignoreCase="true" 
>     baseDN="cn=users,dc=adtest,dc=mycity,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 
>     bindDN="cn=testuser,cn=users,dc=adtest,dc=mycity,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 
>     bindPassword="testuserpwd"
>     ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory"> 
>
>     <activedFilters
>           userFilter="(&amp;(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectcategory=user))"&amp;(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectcategory=user))"
>           groupFilter="(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectcategory=group))"    
>           userIdMap="user:sAMAccountName" 
>           groupIdMap="*:cn" 
>           groupMemberIdMap="memberOf:member"> 
>     </activedFilters>
> </ldapRegistry>
> ```

For more details and other LDAP see [Configuring LDAP user registries with the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ldap.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-4-2-0-1&lang=en)

- JMS - as you didn't provide details, if you are acting as JMS server or client and which JMS provider are you using (default or MQ), check this page as starting point for JMS related configuration - [Liberty profile: JMS messaging](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_messaging.html?lang=en)
- Application migration - if you want to check, if there are any issues with your application code regarding migration, you can install plugin for Eclipse/RAD - 
  [WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit – Liberty Tech Preview](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/2014/04/23/websphere-application-server-migration-toolkit-liberty-tech-preview/) which will scan your code for incompatibilities.

Comment: Thank You so much Gas for your responce and your explanation given me the answer and I will work with this and let you know results. Thaks once again